# Invoke Opportunity Territory Assignment filter from another class

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, visual-workflow, developer-console, territory-management

Can I invoke from another apex class, lwc or flow, ready-made filter class by salesforce ([which described here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_interface_TerritoryMgmt_OpportunityTerritory2AssignmentFilter.htm))?

I tried invoke it through anonymous window in dev console, used next lines of code:

```
List<Id> oppsId = new List<Id>();
List<Opportunity> opps = [Select Id From Opportunity Where Id = 'XXXXXXX'];

oppsId.add(opps[0].Id);

OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter filter = new OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter();
filter.getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments(oppsId);
```

But after I run this code, selected opportunity didn't assign to territory. Maybe I invoke it wrong or we can't invoke it like this?

*If I click on the "filter" button in the territory setup - everyting works well. So territories set up well*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments` method of the `OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter` class doesn't update the db. Instead, it returns a map of the results that you should use.

Try something like this:

```
List<Id> opportunityIds = new List<Id>();
List<Opportunity> opps = [Select Id From Opportunity Where Id = 'XXXXXXX'];
opportunityIds.add(opps[0].Id);

OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter oppTerrAssignFilter = new OppTerrAssignDefaultLogicFilter();
Map<Id, Id> opportunityTerritoryAssignments = oppTerrAssignFilter.getOpportunityTerritory2Assignments(opportunityIds);

for (Id opportunityId : opportunityTerritoryAssignments.keySet()) {
    System.debug('Opportunity Id: ' + opportunityId + ', Assigned Territory2 Id: ' + opportunityTerritoryAssignments.get(opportunityId));
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood! Then I need just to update Territory2Id on the opp, to see changes, correct?

Comment: It depends on where and why you are doing it. But in general I would say so.